# Slickgrid possible bug: only upper rows are visible

Tags: slickgrid

I am working with Slickgrid and only upper rows are being visible. These upper rows update when I scroll down, but the others keep hidden/blank.

The problem is **fixed if you change a column position** with your mouse.

I tried removing some columns, disabling different plugins and calling invalidate/render functions with no success.

Why is it happening? Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating and initializing the grid in the hidden container, so, when it measures the viewport, it thinks that it's got 0 height.  You need to set explicit height on the container and make sure it is visible before you finish grid initialization.